# Single Authentication Scala (PlayFramework) + mobile app

Tags: scala, authentication, playframework, authorization

There is a mobile application that requests a phone number and sends a code from SMS during authentication.

Now I have a request sent to the backend with a phone number that generates a request to the SMS service. The service issues a token, which is sent when the code is confirmed from SMS. If success, I issue a token that lives for a certain time.

It is necessary to do authentication on `Scala` +`PlayFramework`, for example, as in Whats'up, telegram, where the token has an unlimited lifetime.

I have been looking for information for a long time, which libraries to implement this, but I have not found a solution, I will be grateful to the advice.

Comment: It's quite wide and complicated problem, so I'm afraid there is no simple answer, like take X library. First of all have you choose the service for sending SMS with temporary password? If no then probably you can take a look at AWS SNS - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-phone-number-as-subscriber.html - off course if you are planning to deploy your app in AWS eco-system. Otherwise, take a look at your cloud provider services similar SNS. Please, let me highlight this - your question is rather about architecture and infrastructure, the code here - is the easiest part.